# Java Jna and DWORD conversion

Tags: java, jna, dword

I have this dll library interface:

```
int MetEx(BYTE *Data_Ora,DWORD Prezzo)
```

I want to use JNA to call it, so I did this instance mapping:

```
int MetEx(byte[] Data_Ora, int Prezzo);
```

But I'm not very sure the DWORD is well converted to int. Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`DWORD` is equivalent to `int`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md).

There is even a [Java-side `DWORD`](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef.DWORD.html), if you'd like to use that instead.